# My script isn't run in my MVC 5 project

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual Studio 2015 I created a default WEB app with MVC selected.

I created a Javascript file in the "scripts" folder called IanScript.js.

It's content is simply:

```
document.write("hi");
```

I modified the about.cshtml file as follows:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/IanScript.js") <!--My addition-->
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
```

The browser shows the source as including:

```
<h3>Your application description page.</h3>
<script src="/Scripts/IanScript.js"></script>
 <!--My addition-->
```

But doesn't render the text.

Prior to document.write I tried alert. I just want it to do "something"

If I add the below line just after the @Scripts.Render line, it adds "ooo" to the output.

```
<script>document.write("ooo")</script>
```

So I don't understand why it won't run the code in the included script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in a .js file that is just called when it is loaded. You can get the functionality you desire by defining a function in the js file and calling it in a document that includes it.

```
function myJSFileFunction(){
    console.log("1");//or whatever
}
```

....

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/IanScript.js") <!--My addition-->
<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    myJSFileFunction();
</script>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but if I go to http://plnkr.co/ (javascript test environent) and add alert("hi"); to the script.js, it executes my alert in their default html. That has <script src="script.js"></script> in the head tag.

Comment: I don't care about that site. If you include a js file in your program then you have to call a function in what it wraps.

Comment: Well slightly embarrassing, but I fixed it and it now works as expected. My script was called IansScript and I had missed out one of the s's. So you don't actually need to wrap the code in a function and call the function, it's invoked at the point it is included.